# Вывод Up-Sells и Cross-Sells в шаблон Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

появилась проблема вывода Up-Sells и Cross-Sells в самописный шаблон Woocommerce, а именно не могу найти код для вывода.
Можете дать пример?

Answer (score 1):

Up-sells выводится через экшн `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` хук `woocommerce_upsell_display`

сам шаблон `woocommerce/templates/single-product/up-sells.php`

Cross-Sells выводится через экшн `woocommerce_cart_collaterals` хук `woocommerce_cross_sell_display`

сам шаблон `woocommerce/templates/cart/cross-sells.php`